# Turtle.Screen() Fullscreen on Program Startup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to write some code that will start a Screen fullscreen (fill the whole screen without having to click the maximize button)

```
def __init__(self, states = 2):
    self.window = turtle.Screen()
    #self.window.screensize(1920,1080)
    self.window.title('States')
    self.turtles = []
```

self.window.screensize maxes the resolution 1920x1080, but only inside the small screen. To reach the full screen width and height, you have to maximize it. Any way of fixing this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, that also works:

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()

  #set size:

screen.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)

  #remove close,minimaze,maximaze buttons:
canvas = screen.getcanvas()
root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()
root.overrideredirect(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Well after many days of searching, i finally found a solution

```
self.window = turtle.Screen()
self.window.screensize(sizex, sizey)
self.window.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0, startx=None, starty=None)
```

Comment: NameError: global name 'self' is not defined

Comment: @johnktejik, self is the key word , when we use this inside a class

Comment: Is there a way to make it borderless fullscreen ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer code didn't work for me in python3.5. I changed it to the following and it worked correctly.

```
wn.screensize()
wn.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
```

Comment: [`wn.screensize()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.screensize) doesn't do anything here. The docs say "If no arguments are given, return current (canvaswidth, canvasheight)" but you don't do anything with this tuple.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for getting fullscreen ( proved in Replit ) :

1. Get the screen
2. Get the screen's `tkinter` root
3. Set the attribute `-fullscreen` to `True`

Code:

```py
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()
screenTk = screen.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
screenTk.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

Comment: Same effect have `screen.getcanvas().master` and `from tkinter import Widget; Widget._nametowidget(screen.getcanvas(), name='.')` . It's the only true fullscreen, but ... with a thin border. So the remaining question is: > **Is there a way to make it borderless fullscreen?** (asked by VanGo Jan 15, 2021 at 7:48).

Comment: I don't think so...

Answer (score 1):

To get fullscreen, but still have the title bar and buttons use this. Tested.

```py
screen = turtle.Screen()
screenTk = screen.getcanvas().winfo_toplevel()
# maximize window
screenTk.attributes("-zoom", 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for python 2.7.18 its not a true full screen but its as big as the screen

```py
import turtle

screen = turtle.Screen()

screen.setup(width = 1.0, height = 1.0)
```

Comment: Seems like a repeat of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60138928/6243352).