# Run a turtle program in full screen when initiated

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-3.7

I wrote a Python 3.7 program with Turtle Graphics. It is a simple program and works fine, but I want it to run full-screen when I initiate the program. How can I do this? There is no full-screen option in the Turtle documentation.

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

a = turtle.Turtle()
a.speed(10)
a.color('red', 'blue')

# a.begin_fill() 

for i in range(90):
    a.fd(200)
    a.lt(169)

# a.end_fill()


turtle.done()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle.Screen() Fullscreen on Program Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` and `height` arguments to the `setup()` method take integer (pixel) and floating point (percentage of screen).  By supplying `1.0` you'll get the largest window that turtle can make:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

a = Turtle()
a.speed('fastest')
a.color('red', 'blue')

# a.begin_fill()

for _ in range(36):
    a.forward(200)
    a.left(170)

# a.end_fill()

screen.mainloop()
```

But this isn't necessarily the operating systems sense of *Full Screen* where the window overlays *everything*.  It's just the largest window turtle can create given available screen real estate.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This helps me a lot ! But, I don't know why, the window opens in its absolute value, but there seems to be a little space (about less than 10px) in the left edge that seems to not be filled with the Turtle window. It is not a big problem, but i want to know why this happens ! If you can, please respond me ! Thanks !