# How to get your screen height and width on a mac using python?

Tags: python, python-turtle, screen-size

I am writing a program for python turtle and i want it to fill the entire screen. I am using `turtle.screensize()` to try and do it but i don't know my screen resolution.

This is my code:

```
import turtle

tur = turtle.Turtle()
tur.pensize(2)
tur.speed(5)
tur.color("blue")

def triangle():
    for i in range(3): # Triangle
        tur.forward(100)
        tur.left(120)

def square():
    for i in range(4): # Square
        tur.forward(100)
        tur.left(90) # 90 * 4 = 360

def pentagon():
    for i in range(5): # Pentagon
        tur.forward(90)
        tur.left(72) # 72 * 5 = 360

def hexagon():
    for i in range(6): # Hexagon
        tur.forward(80)
        tur.left(60) # 60 * 6 = 360

def heptagon():
    for i in range(7): # Heptagon
        tur.forward(75)
        tur.left(51.4285714286)  # 51.4285714286 * 7 = 360

def octagon():
    for i in range(8): # Octagon
        tur.forward(70)
        tur.left(45) # 45 * 8 = 360

def nonagon():
    for i in range(9): # Nonagon
        tur.forward(65)
        tur.left(40) # 40 * 9 = 360

def decagon():
    for i in range(10): # Decagon
        tur.forward(60)
        tur.left(36) # 36 * 10 = 360

def hendecagon():
    for i in range(11): # Hendecagon
        tur.forward(55)
        tur.left(32.7272727273) # 32.7272727273 * 11 = 360

def duodecagon():
    for i in range(12): # Duodecagon
        tur.forward(50)
        tur.left(30)

def icositetragon():
    for i in range(24): # Icositetragon
        tur.forward(25)
        tur.left(15)

def main():
    print("1 = Triangle \n" + "2 = Square \n" + "3 = Pentagon \n" + "4 = Hexagon \n" + "5 = Heptagon \n" + "6 = Octagon")
    print("7 = Nonagon \n" + "8 = Decagon \n" + "9 = Hendecagon \n" + "10 = Duodecagon \n" + "11 = Icositetragon")
    number = input("Choose a shape number: ")
    if number == "1":
        triangle()
    elif number == "2":
        square()
    elif number == "3":
        pentagon()
    elif number == "4":
        hexagon()
    elif number == "5":
        heptagon()
    elif number == "6":
        octagon()
    elif number == "7":
        nonagon()
    elif number == "8":
        decagon()
    elif number == "9":
        hendecagon()
    elif number == "10":
        duodecagon()
    elif number == "11":
        icositetragon()
    else:
        print("Not a number or number incorrect")
        return
    tur.penup()
    tur.forward(200)

main()

turtle.screensize()
turtle.mainloop()
```

Comment: Fullscreening turtle has been asked: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089578/run-a-turtle-program-in-full-screen-when-initiated), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607735/python-turtle-tk-how-can-i-maximize-the-window), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63856224/how-do-you-make-a-full-screen-in-the-turtle-module)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle.Screen() Fullscreen on Program Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than `screensize()`, what you want is `setup()`, which, along with pixel sizes, accepts floating point values indication what *percentage* of the screen you want.  In your case, this would be `setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)`.  A simple example:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

polygons = [
    (3, "Triangle"),
    (4, "Square"),
    (5, "Pentagon"),
    (6, "Hexagon"),
]

def polygon(sides):
    for _ in range(sides):  # Triangle
        turtle.forward(100)
        turtle.left(360 / sides)

def main():
    for index, (_, name) in enumerate(polygons, start=1):
        print(f"{index} = {name}")

    number = int(input("Choose a shape number: ")) - 1

    if 0 <= number < len(polygons):
        polygon(polygons[number][0])
    else:
        print("Number incorrect")
        return

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.forward(200)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1.0, height=1.0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.pensize(2)
turtle.color('blue')

main()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Under Mac OSX, this doesn't appear to include the screen space taken up by the dock.  But "Automatically hide and show the Dock" in Preferences can take of this.