# How do you make a full screen in the turtle module?

Tags: python, logic, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

So I want to make an app in turtle python. I want the screen to be full screen. So how do I do that?

Here is my code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Example Window")
wn.setup(width=600, height=600)

wn.mainloop()
```

How do I make a full screen?

Comment: Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle.Screen() Fullscreen on Program Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("Example Window")
wn.setup(1.0, 1.0)

wn.mainloop()
```

Among the `setup()` parameters, if either `width` and `height` is an integer, that parameter will evaluated in pixels, if a float, a percentage of the screen. The default size is 50% of screen.

More information at the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.setup

Comment: It's not full screen ... it's maximized window.