# Python Turtle Tk: How can I maximize the window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, python-turtle

Using Python `turtle`, how can I maximize the window?

I can get the Tk Canvas, but Canvas doesn't seem to have a maximize method.

I can set the width and height using `turtle.setup`, but this isn't the same as maximize = e.g. `width=1.0` will overlap the menu bar.

Tk root zoomed doesn't seem to work either, although perhaps I'm not finding the `root` properly.

Comment: Try `turtle.getscreen()._root.state('zoomed')`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turtle.Screen() Fullscreen on Program Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687998/turtle-screen-fullscreen-on-program-startup)

Answer (score 1):

We can't see your code, so it's hard to see what you are trying to achieve, and where it's going wrong. Try these though:

You can use the `setworldcoordinates()` and the `zoomed state`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas

width, height = 640, 480

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
root.state('zoomed')
screen.setworldcoordinates(-width / 2, -height / 2, width / 2 - 1, height / 2 - 1)

screen.mainloop()
```

You could also set the `fullscreen attribute` to `True` like this:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
```